# How to display the reconstructed image from huggingface ViTMAEModel?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using the following code example:

Using the autoencoder, I want to display the recontracted image. How to display it?

```
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, ViTMAEModel
from PIL import Image
import requests

url = "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("facebook/vit-mae-base")
model = ViTMAEModel.from_pretrained("facebook/vit-mae-base")

inputs = image_processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)
last_hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. According to the official doc of [ViTMAE](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/vit_mae), please have a look at [ViT_MAE_visualization_demo.ipynb](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/ViTMAE/ViT_MAE_visualization_demo.ipynb).

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from transformers import ViTFeatureExtractor, ViTMAEForPreTraining
import requests
from PIL import Image

imagenet_mean = np.array(feature_extractor.image_mean)
imagenet_std = np.array(feature_extractor.image_std)

def show_image(image, title=''):
    # image is [H, W, 3]
    assert image.shape[2] == 3
    plt.imshow(torch.clip((image * imagenet_std + imagenet_mean) * 255, 0, 255).int())
    plt.title(title, fontsize=16)
    plt.axis('off')
    return

def visualize(pixel_values, model):
    # forward pass
    outputs = model(pixel_values)
    y = model.unpatchify(outputs.logits)
    y = torch.einsum('nchw->nhwc', y).detach().cpu()
    
    # visualize the mask
    mask = outputs.mask.detach()
    mask = mask.unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1, 1, model.config.patch_size**2 *3)  # (N, H*W, p*p*3)
    mask = model.unpatchify(mask)  # 1 is removing, 0 is keeping
    mask = torch.einsum('nchw->nhwc', mask).detach().cpu()
    
    x = torch.einsum('nchw->nhwc', pixel_values)

    # masked image
    im_masked = x * (1 - mask)

    # MAE reconstruction pasted with visible patches
    im_paste = x * (1 - mask) + y * mask

    # make the plt figure larger
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [24, 24]

    plt.subplot(1, 4, 1)
    show_image(x[0], "original")

    plt.subplot(1, 4, 2)
    show_image(im_masked[0], "masked")

    plt.subplot(1, 4, 3)
    show_image(y[0], "reconstruction")

    plt.subplot(1, 4, 4)
    show_image(im_paste[0], "reconstruction + visible")

    plt.show()


feature_extractor = ViTFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("facebook/vit-mae-base")
url = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11435359/147738734-196fd92f-9260-48d5-ba7e-bf103d29364d.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

pixel_values = feature_extractor(image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values

# make random mask reproducible (comment out to make it change)
torch.manual_seed(2)

model = ViTMAEForPreTraining.from_pretrained("facebook/vit-mae-base")

visualize(pixel_values, model)
```